# How do I get to azure legacy management portal?

Tags: silverlight, caching, azure

Recently, MS added the new Caching service to Azure, still (at this point) in Preview.

I was using the old caching they provided, under the old style legacy silverlight portal.  I have all my apps now working in the new caching world, and would like to ratchet down (and eventually phase out) the old caching service.  However, I no longer seem to have access to the old interface, namely the old legacy silverlight portal to do this.

Anyway know how to get back there temporarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old portal retired on 8th August. All the features except Caching are now available on the new portal, and here is the [link](https://windows.azure.com/) to that.

Comment: Thank you.  I needed this link to the old portal in order to manage my old-style caching as part of deprecating it.  Appreciate the link.  Unable to find it through MS.

Answer (score -1):

FYI- The Silverlight portal will be completely decommissioned on September 1st, 2014. All the Azure Shared Cache which is available via the Silverlight portal will be deleted as well.

Here is the official message : View [Original](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg618005.aspx)
][1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg618005.aspx)
"Please note the Azure Shared Caching service will be retired on September 1, 2014 and with it the Azure Silverlight-based portal. Once the Shared Caching service is retired, all remaining Shared Cache deployments will be deleted. Microsoft strongly encourages you to migrate at the earliest opportunity all existing Shared caches to either the Managed Cache Service (currently in GA) or to the new Azure Redis Cache (currently in Preview). For migration guidance, including guidance for migrating without making code changes, see Migrate from Shared Caching. For more information about the current Azure Cache offerings, see Azure Cache."

Comment: This does not answer the question, but would be appropriate as a comment. Please wait until you have the rep to post comments instead.